# Project TSV file columns by name with AWK

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I am trying to project a TSV file by column name. So far, I took inspiration from a question on SO, and I am using this script, `t.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    split(cols,out,",")
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        ix[$i] = i
}
NR>1 {
    for (i=1;i<=length( out);i++)
        printf "%s%s", $ix[out[i]], OFS
    print ""
}
```

which I can invoke as:

```
awk -f t.awk -v cols=name1,name2,nameN input.tsv
```

It work perfectly, except when one of the names specified by the `cols` attribute does not exists.

How can I modify it in order to make it works also in this cases? I would it to just ignore any non-existing column name passed as parameter.

Example(edit):
Consider the input.tsv:

```
a    b    c
1    2    3
2    3    4
5    6    7
```

I would like the command:

```
awk -f t.awk -v cols=a,c,batman input.tsv
```

to produce:

```
a    c
1    3
2    4
5    7
```

but, so far, it gives:

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "batman"
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and let us know what is not working?

Comment: Which `awk` version are you using? `GNU Awk 4.1.3` produces some random output for the sample invocation.

Comment: Currently I am on MacOS, and it reports: awk version 20070501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your awk script as this:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    split(cols, out, ",")
    for (i in out)
       c[out[i]]
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       if ($i in c)
          hdr[i] = $i
}
{
    k=0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if (i in hdr)
           printf "%s%s", (k++?OFS:""), $i
    print ""
}
```

Then run it as:

```
awk -f t.awk -v cols=a,c,batman input.tsv
```

or:

```
awk -f t.awk -v cols=c,batman,a input.tsv
```

both will produce this output:

```
a   c
1   3
2   4
5   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler rewrite

```
$ awk -v cols='a,c,x' -v d=',' 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(d cols d ~ d $i d) ix[i]} 
                                      {for(i in ix) printf "%s", $i OFS;
                                       print ""}' file

a c
1 3
2 4
5 7
```

column order may not be preserved though.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    numIdxs = split(cols,idx2name,/,/)
}
NR==1 {
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        name2nr[$fldNr] = fldNr
    }
    next
}
{
    for (idx=1; idx<=numIdxs; idx++) {
        name = idx2name[idx]
        if (name in name2nr) {
            fldNr  = name2nr[name]
            fldVal = $(name2nr[fldNr])
            printf "%s%s", (numPrinted++ ? OFS : ""), fldVal
        }
    }
}
numPrinted { print ""; numPrinted=0 }
```

Trust me, you'll be much happier when you encounter rainy day cases and if you have to look back and enhance it later.

Note that, like your original script, the above will output fields in the order you specify on the command line rather than the order they occur in the input file so you can rearrange columns from the command line if you like.